# Contract function only works on array with one item

Tags: solidity, remix, oracles, 1inch-dex-aggregator

I have created a contract to loop over an array of token addresses and call the 1inch oracle. It only works when the token array is of length 1. Have been testing on remix.

when inputting the token array:

This Works:
`["0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f"] #DAI`

This Does not Work
`["0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f","0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48"] #DAI,USDC`

error message: `call to OneInchOracleQuery.getRatesToEth errored: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert`

Contract Code:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;


interface IOffchainOracle {

    function getRate(
        address srcToken,
        address dstToken,
        bool useWrappers
    ) external view returns (uint256);

    function getRateToEth(address srcToken, bool useSrcWrappers) external view returns (uint256);

}

contract OneInchOracleQuery {

    function getRatesToEth(address[] calldata _tokens, address _oracle) external view returns (uint256[] memory){
        uint256[] memory result = new uint256[](_tokens.length);
        IOffchainOracle offChainOracle = IOffchainOracle(_oracle);
        for (uint i = 0; i < _tokens.length; i++){
            result[i] = offChainOracle.getRateToEth(_tokens[i], false);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

1inch docs: https://docs.1inch.io/docs/spot-price-aggregator/introduction

oracle address: https://etherscan.io/address/0x07D91f5fb9Bf7798734C3f606dB065549F6893bb

Comment: the args you've written don't fit the function signature. the function's firt param takes an array of `address`, the second param just a single address. That doesn't fit with either of the example parameters above

Comment: sorry I thought it was clear that my example inputs were only for the first param `_tokens`

Comment: ah. I see. t seems the problem is assigning to the array inside the loop, nothing is working for me now so I can test anymore

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that the problem is and issue external to your contract.

if I change the code as below, the following args work fine,

```
[0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f, 0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f], 0x07D91f5fb9Bf7798734C3f606dB065549F6893bb
```

but not if calling the oracle function. So, for whatever reason, I'm only having an issue with calling the oracle function. The rest of the code is works as expected

```
function getRatesToEth(address[] calldata _tokens, address _oracle) external view returns (uint256[] memory){
    uint256[] memory result = new uint256[](_tokens.length);
    IOffchainOracle offChainOracle = IOffchainOracle(_oracle);
    for (uint i = 0; i < _tokens.length; i++){
        result[i] = i;//offChainOracle.getRateToEth(_tokens[i], false);
        console.log(result[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: funny I tried the exact same. Did you try with only one token in the arg array? The oracle seems to work...

Comment: yeah, it did seem to work for me at first, but then it stopped working, which is why I wrote for whatever reason. :-p Makes me wonder if there is a rate limit or something for requests and two requests in quick succession gets denied by the oracle. but anyway, it's definitely only down to the oracle call as your code handles multiple args fine